# Searching for an object in 2 arraylists

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two arraylists of two types of objects. They are two types of users. I input an id(both types of users have unique integer ids), and want to find out if the user exists among the two arraylists.

```
ArrayList<Artist> artist = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<Customer> customer = new ArrayList();

class Artist implements User{
      private String name;
      private int a_id = 0;
      private ArrayList<ArrayList> albums = new ArrayList();
      private int money;
      private int ma = 999;
      private int mi = 100;

      public Artist(String name) {
          this.name = name;
          a_id = (int)(Math.random()*((ma - mi) + 1)) + mi;
      }
}
...<i>getters and setters</i>

class Customer implements User {
      private String name;
      private int subscription = 1;
      private int due = 0;
      private int c_id = 0;
      private int ma = 9999;
      private int mi = 1000;

      public Customer(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        c_id = (int) (Math.random() * ((ma - mi) + 1)) + mi;
      }
}
    ...<i>getters and setters</i>
```

Comment: I know how to search in a single arraylist, but since the user could be either an artist or a customer, i have to have a simultaneous search in both types of users. That I don't know how to approach.

Comment: I would use a combination of `reduce` to create a single `Stream<User>`, `filter` to locate the correct `id` and then `findFirst` to get the `User` if present.

Comment: What does the `User` interface  look like, any `getId()` method in it?

Comment: User only has a stream method, since artists and customers are separate, i gave separate ranges for their ids, to make a distinction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `anyMatch` method and `||`:

```
public boolean exist(ArrayList<Artist> artist, ArrayList<Customer> customer, int id) {
    return artist.stream().anyMatch(user -> user.getA_id() == id) ||
            customer.stream().anyMatch(user -> user.getC_id() == id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should think about having only one list of type User, because Artist and Customer are of type user (they both implement that interface).
Then you could simply use the stream api to determine wether a userId is there or not:

```
Optional<User> searchedUser = userList.stream().filter(User::getId.equals(userId).findFirst();

if(searchedUser.isPresent()) { //do something and handle missing }
```

Comment: The only issue with that is I require to have separate lists for both as all the other queries either only deal with one of them at a time. However, I could try to  make a parallel list combining all users, if that is what you are suggesting.

Comment: for using a parallel approach, see @Sun answer. he tried with ´anyMatch()´